# simple php explanation.. what's the difference between the arrow operators?

Tags: php

I'm unfamiliar with exact differences between these two operators:

```
->
```

and

```
=>
```

Are there many differences? One assigns an array, and the other just renames or something to that effect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`->` is a method call or property call operator, and `=>` is an array assigning operator

```
$foo = new Bar();
$foo->test();
// or even
$foo->bar = 'baz';

// vs 

$foo = array(
    'bar' => 'test'
);

// And wrapping it all together!!!
$foo = new Bar();
$foo->baz = array( 'bar' => 'baz' );
```

Answer (score 0):

-> is a this operator which is used for accessing class properties whereras

=> is a used for  arrays

Answer (score 0):

`->` is used to access a property of an object where as `=>` is used to marry a array key up with its value during assignment.